# How much delay does two linux commands have in between? If the first one is run with &

Tags: linux, background-process, prompt

Basically I am writing a report to convince the audience that the following Linux commands

```
$ a.sh &
$ b.sh &
$ c.sh &
```

are all started almost at the same time. I couldn't find a good explanation or reliable source to convince the audience. Is there any books or articles that specifically discussed about this? Thanks.

Comment: It's completely false that the three commands start at almost the same time.  For example, in a script with a dozen copies of the line `date +%N & sleep 3&`, there was 400 microseconds average delay between command line starts on my Intel i3-2120 Linux 3.11.0 system, and even the minimum delay was appreciably large, about 50 us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Bash docs

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the background. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true). When job control is not active (see Job Control), the standard input for asynchronous commands, in the absence of any explicit redirections, is redirected from /dev/null.

For more details take a look at the [Bash tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html)

Comment: Hi Saif, this is exactly what I was looking for. But how do I cite this as one of my reference in IEEE style if I were to put this to a report or paper?

Comment: You can give the reference from the documentation alone. What more powerful reference to some concept than the docs itself. You can also explain that there aren't threads in bash, but there is a concept of asynchronous programming that can be achieved with this concept. And then cite the docs.